# Cordova - iOS - Can't allow all orientations

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-build, cordova-cli

I recently switched over from Phongegap Build to cordova locally.  I cannot for the life of me figure out how to get the orientation in iOS to allow all.  It's driving me insane.

I've tried all the documented methods in the config such as:

```
<platform name="ios">
    <preference name="orientation" value="all" />
</platform>
```

But that doesn't work.  I've also tried to manually set the plist attributes via a [plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-settings-hook), but that doesn't seem to do the trick either.  What am I missing here? When I open up the .ipa file, the plist in there only has the following for the orientation attributes:

```
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
<array>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
</array>
```

From my understanding, there should be four like so:

```
<array>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
</array>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preference names are case-insensitive, the correct entry has to be:

```
<preference name="Orientation" value="all" />
```

docs: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/dev/config_ref/index.html#preference

The cordova-custom-config is great if you need specific values for iPad and iPhone.

Comment: Sorry, I tried this already as well.  It didn't work.  I'm so confused.

Comment: @gabaum10  <platform name="ios"><preference name="Orientation" value="all" /> </platform> works perfectly for me. Could you please let us kknow which version of cordova are you using? Also could you post your complete config.xml? May be you have to remove and re-add ios platform after making the case sensitive "Orientation" change

Comment: Holy crap, I had to remove the project and re-add it again.

Comment: Or alternatively, it appears you can run `cordova clean` on the project.  That should do it as well, I think.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [cordova-custom-config](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-custom-config) plugin to achieve this - after installing the plugin to your local project add the following to your config.xml:

```
<platform name="ios">

    <!-- Set orientation on iPhone -->
    <config-file platform="ios" target="*-Info.plist" parent="UISupportedInterfaceOrientations">
        <array>
            <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
            <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
            <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
            <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
        </array>
    </config-file>

    <!-- Set orientation on iPad -->
    <config-file platform="ios" target="*-Info.plist" parent="UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad">
        <array>
            <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
            <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
            <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
            <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
        </array>
    </config-file>
```

You should be able to see the relevant orientations are set in the plist if you open the project in XCode.

Comment: How is this different than the plugin I used (and linked) in my orirginal post?  https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-settings-hook  It looks like it does the same thing, and I know it works for other attributes.  I use it to successfully set the `CFBundleShortVersionString` attribute.  Also, the example they provide they set an orientation property.

Comment: I have used it in the past to do this very thing. There's an [example project](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-custom-config-example) for the plugin which [illustrates setting the orientation attributes on iOS](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-custom-config-example/blob/master/config.xml#L119). There may now be an "official" Cordova way to do it, as it's while since I was looking into this.

Comment: This is a nice idea, but overkill.  See the accepted solution.  The problem was, for some reason the config.xml was not being updated when I updated my config.xml in the www folder.  I have no idea why, but the accepted answer is the right way to do this.

Comment: Agreed that in your case Cordova now provides a solution. But if need to produce a Cordova-based app with different orientation requirements for iPad and iPhone (I do), this is still the only way to do it (natively).